# I am trying to calculate the Distance Between 2 points in Java

Tags: java

import java.util.Random;

```
class MainLab_2 {
    private static Random rand;

    private static int getInt() {
        int z = rand.nextInt() * 100;
        return z;
    }

    private void getTwoPoints(Point p1, Point p2) {
        this.p1 = p1;
        this.p2 = p2;
    }

    private static void main(String[] args) {
        Point p1 = new Point(getInt(), getInt());
        Point p2 = new Point(getInt(), getInt());
    }
}

class Point {
    private static int x, y;

// Default Constructor 
    public Point() {
    }

// Other constructor
    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

// Copy constructor
    public Point(Point p) {
        this(p.x, p.y);
    }

    private static double distance(Point p) {
        return Math.sqrt((p.y - this.y) * (p.y - this.y)
                + (p.x - this.x) * (p.x - this.x));
    }

   // Accessor Method   
   public double getDistance(Point p) {
        return  distance(Point p);
   }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
   }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

// Mutator Method
    public void set(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Given Point (%d, %d%n)", getX(),
                getY());
    }
}

class Line {
    private static Point p1, p2;

    public Line() {

    }

    public Line(Point p1, Point p2) {
        this(p1);
        this.p2 = new Line(p2);
    }

    public Line(Line aline) {
        this(aline.p1, aline.p2);
    }

    // Accessor Method
    public double getDistance() {   
       return Point.getDistance(Point p);
   }

    public Point getP1() {
        return p1;
    }

    public Point getP2() {
        return p2;
    }

// Mutator Method
    public void set(Point p1, Point p2) {
        this.p1 = p1;
        this.p2 = p2;
    }

    private String toString() { 
        return String.format ("Line (Point(%d,%d), Point(%d,%d), distance = %d%n )", 
                            p1.x,p1.y,p2.x,p2.y,getDistance())
   }
```

As attached above, is my script.

Firstly I'm trying to randomly generate any 2 number from -99 to 99.

After generating I'll pass this 2 number into my class Point as 
(x, y).

Generate 2 points (p.x, p.y) and (this.x, this.y) before calculating the distance between the 2 points. The formula I'm currently using was found online.

My End Results to get is a few sets of e.g

Set 1

Given Point (-13,90)

Given Point (39, 16)

Line (Point (-13,90),Point (39, 16), distance = 90.4434 )

---

Set 2

Given Point (89,24)

Given Point (33, -68)

Line (Point (89,24),Point (23, -68), distance = 113.2254 )

---

I hope to random 2 numbers from my main class and pass it to my class Point. And in my class Line I'm able to generate 2 points and calculate the distance between them. However, I'm unable to do that. with my current script. It will be very helpful if somebody can give me some guidance on how I can correct it. I'm fairly new to java and really hope I can get some pointers and step by step guidance on this. Thank you.

Comment: What is your actual question that you want an answer to? Please see [ask].

Comment: Im sorry,  my question is how can I random 2 numbers from my main class and pass it to my class Point. And in my class Line I'm able to generate 2 points and calculate the distance between them.

Comment: A. You need to read/practice more on the subject of variable scoping. There are several things in the code you've posted that indicate that you're understanding is incomplete. (specifically in your constructor and in your static distance method) B. There already is a Point class in Java (java.awt.Point). C. Start more simply. Create two hardcoded points, and test your distance formula with these before trying to randomly generate Points.

Comment: Amend your question to clarify what you want to do. And BTW, the distance formula is the Pythagorean theorem and `Math.hypot` provides that.

Comment: Style Note: Object methods often have verbs in their names because they _do_ something. Typically, we choose the verb so that it makes sense to the _caller_ of the method. For example, if some `class Bar` has a method named `getFoo(...)`, most programmers will understand that you call it to _get_ the "foo" _from_ the `Bar` object. Your "getTwoPoints" method does just the opposite. Most programmers would call it "setTwoPoints(...)" because the caller calls it to _set_ the object's `p1` and `p2` member variables.

Answer (score 1):

This does not address your question as you have serious problems in your code.  This will point some of them out to you.

```
class MainLab_2 {
```

There are no points `p1`, and `p2` in class MainLab_2.  Nor is it clear why this method should even be here.

```
    private void getTwoPoints(Point p1, Point p2) {
        this.p1 = p1;
        this.p2 = p2;
    }
```

The main entry point needs to be public

```
    private static void main(String[] args) {
        Point p1 = new Point(getInt(), getInt());
        Point p2 = new Point(getInt(), getInt());
    }
}
```

---

```
class Point {
```

These should not be static, otherwise all your points will have the same values as the last one you created.  They need to be instance fields.

```
    private static int x, y;
```

You can't use `this` within a static context. A static method has no idea what `this` refers to.

```
    private static double distance(Point p) {
        return Math.sqrt((p.y - this.y) * (p.y - this.y)
                + (p.x - this.x) * (p.x - this.x));
    }
```

---

```
class Line {
```

Once again theses should not be static.

```
    private static Point p1, p2;
```

you have no single argument Line constructor, nor would it make sense.

```
 public Line(Point p1, Point p2) {
        this(p1); // <-- this constructor reference doesn't exist
        this.p2 = new Line(p2);
    }
```

This won't be of much use making it private.  It should be able to called by
all users of this class.

```
    private String toString() { 
        return String.format ("Line (Point(%d,%d), Point(%d,%d), distance = %d%n )", 
                            p1.x,p1.y,p2.x,p2.y,getDistance())
   }
```

To summarize.

- Understand the difference between static and non-static
- Read up on constructors and how they should be used.
- learn about the different access modifiers.

Check out [The Java Tutotals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) for more information.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple solution using **immutable** objects.

**Point.java**

```
public class Point {

    private static final int LOW = -100;

    private static final int HIGH = 100;

    private static final Random rand = new Random();

    private static int rand() {
        return rand.nextInt(HIGH - LOW) + LOW;
    }

    private final int x;

    private final int y;

    public Point() {
        this(rand(), rand());
    }

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public double getDistance(Point p) {
        return Math.hypot(x - p.x, y - p.y);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Point [x=" + x + ", y=" + y + "]";
    }

}
```

**Line.java**

```
public class Line {

    private final Point p1;

    private final Point p2;

    private final double length;

    public Line() {
        this(new Point(), new Point());
    }

    public Line(Point p1, Point p2) {
        this.p1 = p1;
        this.p2 = p2;
        this.length = p1.getDistance(p2);
    }

    public Point getP1() {
        return p1;
    }

    public Point getP2() {
        return p2;
    }

    public double getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Line [p1=" + p1 + ", p2=" + p2 + ", length=" + length + "]";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Line l1 = new Line();
        Line l2 = new Line();
        System.out.println(l1);
        System.out.println(l2);
    }

}
```